# how do I change markdown mode to org-mode in Jekyll config.yaml?

Tags: jekyll

I would like to use org-mode markdown in Jekyll. I gem-installed `org-ruby`, and added the `markdown: org` line in the YAML config file, but I get an error saying that org is not valid.

How do I specify that I want to use org-mode markdown in jekyll?

Answer (score 4):

org-mode is not native in Jekyll, you need to use a plugin. Try [jekyll-org-mode-converter](https://github.com/tjaartvdwalt/jekyll-org-mode-converter)