# Is there a way to make github pages support org-mode?

Tags: emacs, jekyll, blogs, org-mode, github-pages

I like authoring in `org-mode` much better than in `markdown`. It offers much more features such as `LaTeX` support, spreadsheet-like table support , outline view etc.

I like github pages because it supports `jekyll` based static sites. So I don't have to generate/publish my blog posts from `markdown`/`org-mode` into `html`. I also don't have to maintain two version controlled repositories : one is generated static html/css for github pages, the other is the markdown/org-mode source.

Currently, even though github does [support org-mode](https://github.com/github/markup) source through `org-ruby`, github pages doesn't.

So I was wondering if there is a way to make github pages support `org-mode` natively, possibly through the same `org-ruby`, so that I can just have one `jekyll` based github pages repository, and author blogs in org-mode in it without publishing/generating htmls, just like I can in `markdown`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to maintain two separate repositories, you can always use two branches in the same repository. One with the org-mode text and scripts to convert, the other with the static html that is published in Jekyll.

As shown in [how do I change markdown mode to org-mode in Jekyll config.yaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34022086/how-do-i-change-markdown-mode-to-org-mode-in-jekyll-config-yaml), Jekyll does not natively support `org-mode`